# C hide file inside assembler

Tags: c, shell

I wanna hide same files (bash file (text)) inside my C code then call it at run time atm i do this thing but it is not good cause it is not easy manage all bash code easy i wanna to do something like bash1.sh, bash2.sh, bash3.sh ... inside C code then call it always inside code without use #define cause then it more easy edit .sh files on source.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
echo \"hello\" \n\
echo \"how are you\" \n\
echo \"today\" \n\
"
/*Also you can write using char array without using MACRO*/
/*You can do split it with many strings finally concatenate 
  and send to the system(concatenated_string); */

int main()
{
    system(SHELLSCRIPT);    //it will run the script inside the c code. 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the assembler tag?

Comment: You can use probably `sed`, or other external tool (maybe base64 encoder) to preprocess input .sh files into some `const char file_content = "....";`, just create some makefile rule to process the ".sh" files into ".sh_c_str" file, and then `#include "script1.sh_c_str"` in the source. If you are building the project with GNU make and your own custom Makefile, and you understand how it works... an art which has been sadly long lost and replaced by weird things like Autotools/etc...

Comment: @Ped7g> [`xxd -i`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) is very convenient for that. You might want to insert a `const` keyword at the beginning of its output though.

Comment: @spectras base64 is more dense than hex, and if the goal is obfuscation, I would even go the length to do my own encoding+trivial_encryption (base64 extended alphabet + some trivial scrambler). Then again the OP titled this "hide", and then he puts plain text into binary, which is confusing. EDIT: oh, now I see what xxd -i does. Still own baseXX alphabet would be more obfuscated.

Comment: @Ped7g> actually, it produces binary. It is written as hexadecimal to embed it in C code, but the final symbol actually embedded will be a verbatim copy of the file. Granted, if the goal was obfuscating and not embedding, that's a miss :)

Answer (score 1):

InternetAussie nicely answered the C string literal part already. However, it does not really look better than the macro definition, does it? Trying to have the shell code as array and concatenate the strings would only spare you having to add the newline character, so...

If you are after being able to modify the shell scripts as easily as possible **and** if you are willing to invest some time for initially, then write a shell script translator.

You would then write your shell scripts just as normally, easiest you can get probably, and let the IDE generate C code from them using your translator on every build, if the shell script changed.

Depending on your IDE, you might install a prebuild task, include some makefiles or whatever is offered for.

The C code generated would contain the shell script either as a define (in a header file you could include then) or global a global string constant just as in the already mentioned answer (in a source file).

A sample parser might look like this (incomplete, you yet have to put some hands on; as this is a C question, I provide C code, but you could use anything suitable else, like perl, too):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char const* getCFileName(char const*)
{
    return 0; // replace .sh with .c?
}
char const* getVariableName(char const*)
{
    return 0; // find appropriate global variable name!
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return -1;
    FILE* in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!in)
        return -1;
    FILE* out = fopen(getCFileName(argv[1]), "w");
    if (!out)
    {
        fclose(in);
        return -1;
    }
    // filename possibly given in argv or derived from either argv1/2
    fprintf(out, "char const* const %s = \n", getVariableName(argv[1]));
    char buffer[1024];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in))
    {
        // escape special characters in buffer: '\', '"', ...
        // replace the terminating newline character with "\n", tabs with "\t", ...
        fprintf(out, "    \"%s\"\n", buffer);
    }
    fprintf(out, "%s", "    \"\";\n");
    // (included empty string for the case the file is empty - if so,
    //  generated C code still is valid...)

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Ped7g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4271923/ped7g) you can use a tool like `base64` in order to convert the contents of your script into an in-[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded string, so that it contains no characters that need to be escaped inside a C string literal.

Consider the following sample script `bash1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello world
```

You encode its contents by means of `base64`:

```
base64 bash1.sh > bash1.base64
```

The in-Base64-encoded contents are:

```
cat bash1.base64
IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKZWNobyBoZWxsbyB3b3JsZAo=
```

After that, you need somehow to "place the contents of this file into a C string":

```
const char *bash1_64 = "IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKZWNobyBoZWxsbyB3b3JsZAo=";
```

You achieve that with the following Perl *one-liner*:

```
perl -lne 'print qq<const char * bash1_64 = "$_";>' bash1.base64 > bash1.h
```

After that, the header file `bash1.h` contains the string `bash1_64`. You can already include this header file in your source files.

The steps shown above could be collected and generalized, for instance, in a *Makefile* or in a *shell script*.

From now on, you have to decide how are you going to **decode** the string containing the script to be run:

1. You could **decode** the contents of this string before passing it to `system()`.
2. You could create a common *common* shell script which is called by `system()`. This script takes a string encoded in base64 as an argument, it **decodes** it, and then it run its contents. Decoding a in-base64-encoded string can be easily done inside a shell script by passing the option `-d` to the `base64` program.

Comment: thanks for you info i found a solution with your answer: